# How to properly handle max/min int value edge case-Java

Tags: java

I am working on a problem from LeetCode (not an interview question just practicing) that asks the following:

`Given a sorted integer array nums, where the range of elements are in the inclusive range [lower, upper], return its missing ranges.`

The code that I came up with fails for inputs where the `nums` array is `[-2147483648,2147483647]` and `lower/upper` are `-2147483648/2147483647` respectively. The part of my code that actually answers the question is:

```
if (nums[0]-lower > 1) {
    String range = lower + "->" + (nums[0]-1);
    ans.add(range);
}
else if (nums[0]-lower == 1) {
    String range = new Integer(lower).toString();
    ans.add(range);
}
for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] - nums[i-1] > 2) {
            String range = nums[i-1]+1 + "->" + (nums[i]-1);
            ans.add(range);
        }
        else if (nums[i] - nums[i-1] == 2) {
            String range = new Integer(nums[i]-1).toString();
            ans.add(range);
        }
    }
```

I was wondering how best to handle this edge case, not just for this question but generally. Do I just add extra `if-statements` to my code to specifically handle these two numbers (or if addition/subtraction of numbers causes the int value to overflow) or is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Comment: Link requires sign-up.

Comment: Ah ok. I'll remove the link. I posted the whole question above. If more information is needed please ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum value of an `int` is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 which is 2147483647, but the difference between that number and *any* negative number is larger than that number itself.

So all your subtraction expressions like `nums[0]-lower` overflow with `[-2147483648,2147483647]` (or `[-1,2147483647]`).

You can check it with this:

```
System.out.println(2147483647 - -1);
```

This prints out `-2147483648` even though you would expect it to be `2147483648`.

One easy fix is to do the calculations as a 64-bit `long`. Change all your subtractions like below to cast the expression to `long`.

```
if (nums[0] - (long)lower > 1) {
```

Take the above example and change it to:

```
System.out.println(2147483647 - (long) -1);
```

This will correctly print `2147483648`.